# How do I get php5-gd to work?

Tags: php, debian, gd

[**imageantialias**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php) doesn't seem to work using PHP 5.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imageantialias()

The packages `php5-gd` and `libjpeg62` were already installed and I even installed `php5-imagick` and restarted apache. Still I can't use the GD library under PHP 5.

I tried approaches that were described in forums and on StackOverflow, but I just can't get GD running. I am using the latest release (8.3) of Debian.

On additional research, `php -m` shows that **gd** is loaded. However, I didn't see the files `libjpeg.so.*` in `/usr/lib`. Maybe this is the problem?

Also, according to phpinfo, GD seems to be installed

[image: gd]

**How do I install GD for PHP 5?**

Comment: Is it loaded? `php -m` should include 'gd'.

Comment: Yes, I have already checked that and I also updated the question to clarify that. Also, strangely `libjpeg.so.*` is not found in `/usr/lib`. I don't know why, but maybe this could be the problem? When I call `apt-get install libjpeg62`, it states "Note, selecting 'libjpeg62-turbo' instead of 'libjpeg62'
libjpeg62-turbo is already the newest version."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package *php5-gd* is working. Only `imageantialias()` is not implemented in the PHP packages in Debian Jessie. If you try any other function from the `GD` library it should work.

The reason behind php5-gd in Debian Jessie not providing that function is explained at [bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=778596) (closed as "won't fix"). I don't understand it enough to give a summary.

Not in the scope of the question and because of that I won't quote it here, but you may be interested in it anyway: In the same bug report someone wrote down a solution that can be found at [forums.debian.net](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=560389#p560389).

This issue at the official dglib repo may be of interest, too: https://github.com/libgd/libgd/issues/115

Comment: I already tried to install php from unstable repositories, because I wanted to install PHP 7. However, then, phpMyAdmin will become incompatible and god knows what other apts, too.

Comment: This task took quite some time to finish, but I finally have a working GD lib, thank you!

Comment: Later on, I discovered that while `php-gd` is on hold, it also puts other packages, like `php` on hold, too. Or at least I can't update them anymore...